# Image distortion with ImageMagick

Tags: c#, image, imagemagick, perspective

I am less than a C# begginer. Actually, I am forced to use it because I need to develop an application which can merge image sound and video into a single video.

For that I am using FFMPEG, ImageMagick and C# on VS. The thing is that I can't get the code to work. I just simply want to distort the image. I installed ImageMagick in the computer, I added the reference in VS and I am using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using ImageMagick;

    namespace ImageDistor
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(@"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\project\test.jpg"))
            {
                image.Distort(DistortMethod.Perspective, new double[] { 0, 0, 20, 60, 90, 0, 70, 63, 0, 90, 5, 83, 90, 90, 85, 88 });
                image.Write(@"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\project\output.jpg");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I wrote all the code, basicly because I don't know what I am doing, I am a PHP, CSS, Jquery, type of programmer, so please parton my ignorance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ 0,0 20,60 90,0 70,63 0,90 5,83 90,90 85,88 }
```

From memory the definition of points changed a few years ago and if you have an old version you may need to use something a bit different.

Comment: Hey Bonzo! Thanx for the answer! I dropped me an error. I don't know if I can pasted here because it's long... but I might be because I have I think a version from 2013. The thing is that when I download the new one it didn't with a "resize" example and the old one worked, so I kept the old one. I might dowloaded a wrong file.

If you could send me a link of the right file would be helpful I am running windows 7 at the moment

Comment: Here are the errors:

`Error 1 } expected C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ImageDistor\ImageDistor\Form1.cs 27 77 ImageDistor
Error 2 Invalid expression term ',' C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ImageDistor\ImageDistor\Form1.cs 27 79 ImageDistor` ... etc

Comment: The old version is the "Magick.NET-6.8.6.601-Q16-x86-net40-client" and the new, the one is not working even for resizing is "Magick.NET-7.0.2.400-Q8-x64"